# Assign label to its corresponding grid cell (Yolo)

Tags: python, numpy, keras, multidimensional-array, yolo

I coded a YOLO model from scratch and have a numpy array which looks like this:

```
[
 [[1 0 1 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1]
 [1 1 0 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
 ...]
```

This is how it would look in a pandas object:

```
Obj_score c1 c2 x y h w 
1 0 1 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1
1 1 0 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

In order to make my model work I have to convert the mentioned label tensor into a `S*S*(B*5+C)` tensor, where I have to put each label into its corresponding grid cell. How would I do that?

My model makes 3 bounding box predictions (B), 2 class predictions, and it S = 7.
So how would I put my labels into its corresponding grid cell?